# Set a String to "" or leave it null?

Tags: java, string, null, initialization

I have some String variables which are getting the values from invoking the function `getParameter()` and some of this variables will probably be `null`.

Later, I will evaluate this variables using `equals()` method. 
Should I set all the String variables to the empty String (`""`) if they are `null` to avoid any problems?

Comment: Are you talking about the String literal `"null"` (i.e. 4 characters) or are you talking about the value `null`?

Comment: I'm talking about the value null

Comment: <pedant>null isn't a value, it's the lack of one</pedant>

Comment: @<pedant>: Read http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.7 : "The null type has one value, the null reference, represented by the literal null [...]"

Comment: even the JLS gets it wrong sometimes :)

Comment: @skaffman null is a valid value for a reference

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have three options - 
If the item you are comparing too is known not to be null (e.g. a constant) then use that first.

```
if ("hello".equals(variable)) { ... }
```

Check for null first

```
if (variable != null && variable.equals("hello")) { ... }
```

Finally if null and the empty string can be considered the same down stream then set the string to the empty string. But if you wish to handle null differently then you can not do this.

Comment: i prefer  **if ("hello".equals(variable))**

Comment: The syntax of the first option is "icky", I believe that is the technical term.

The second option I'm not keen on as I've seen far too many programmers stuff up even simple boolean operations like that.

Given a choice I go for StringUtils...

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to is to use a static util method to do the compare. Apache commons-lang [StringUtils.equals(String,String)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#equals(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) is a possible with clearly defined behaviour for nulls.

```
// null safe compare
if (StringUtils.equals(variable,"hello")) {...}

// is "" or null 
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(variable)) { ... }

// with static imports it's a bit nicer
if (isNotEmpty(var1) && isEmpty(var2)) { ... }
```